# How can I use PowerShell to set the default document in IIS?

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I'm configuring a web site using PowerShell and I want to set the default document.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
$metabasePath = "IIS://Localhost/W3SVC"
$iisNumber = "12345"
$site = new-object 
        System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("$metabasePath/$iisNumber/root")
$site.psbase.Properties["DefaultDoc"].Value = 
    "newdefdoc.htm," + $site.psbase.Properties["DefaultDoc"].Value
$site.psbase.CommitChanges()
```

The value returned in `$site.psbase.Properties["DefaultDoc"].Value` is a comma separated list of documents so you may need to re-jig the order to suit your case. The example above just adds a new default document (`newdefdoc.htm`) to the top of the list.